# Dynamically add select option with options from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How do I create a dynamic select input with options from PHP whenever I click on a button?

The working should go like this:

Whenever I click on a button, a select element with options from PHP should be available to choose from.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product">Products:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="product[]" multiple required>
            <option selected="selected">--SELECT PRODUCT--</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on a button, I should be able to create a new select input with the above-mentioned code.

Comment: Are the options being built dependent on any value from the clicked button? Yes: You will need ajax. No: You can get away with prebuilding and just show/hide with js.

Comment: The options are not dependent upon the button click.  The options are common for all select input. I just need a way to add select input on button click

Comment: You can add class to your option with display:none. And use jquery to change it to display: block https://jsfiddle.net/46sk0zqL/4/

Comment: You don't need ajax then. It would be overkill for this. Michael presented a starter for how to toggle elements with a button.

Comment: What I am looking for is to create a new select input whenever I click on a button and that select button should take options from PHP

Answer (score 0):

here you need to use ajax like below

```
function getOptions(query){
   $.post(endPoint, query, function(response){
      $('select[name="product[]"]').empty();
      response.forEach(function(value){
        $('select[name="product[]"]').append("<option value='" +value+ "'></option>");
      });
   })
}
```

and trigger it on click

```
$('body').on('click', '#myButton', function(){
    getOptions(null);
});
```